# closed set with unique distance minimizing element is convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

There is a theorem:

> Let $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a closed, convex set. Then $\forall x \in \mathbb R^n$, there exists a unique $\bar x \in K$ such that $d(x, K) = d(x, \bar x)$. Furthermore, $\forall y \in K$, $\langle x-\bar x, y - \bar x \rangle \leq 0$.

I was thinking about the converse of this statement. Consider these two assumptions.

1. Suppose that $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ is closed. For all $x \in \mathbb R^n$, there exists a unique $\bar x \in K$ such that $d(x,\bar x) = d(x, K)$.
2. For all $x \in \mathbb R^n$, there exists a unique $\bar x \in K$ with the following property: for all $z \in K$, $\langle z - \bar x, x - \bar x\rangle \leq 0$ (i.e. angle greater than right angle).

Are there counterexamples for the following statements?

1. Condition $ 1\Rightarrow$ $K$ is convex.
2. Condition $ 2 \Rightarrow K$ is convex.
3. Condition $ 1 $ and $2 \Rightarrow K$ is convex.

edit: 2. implies 1. So it really boils down to verifying whether condition 1. implies convexity of $K$

Proof: Suppose 2. I shall show that for any $z \in K$, $d(x, z) \geq d(x, \bar x)$.   By pythagoras theorem, I have
\begin{align*}
d(x,z)^2 &= d(x,\bar x)^2 + d(\bar x, z)^2 - 2\langle x-\bar x, z - \bar x\rangle \\
&\geq d(x, \bar x)^2 + d(\bar x, z)^2 \quad \quad \text{(by assumption)} \\
&\geq d(x, \bar x)^2
\end{align*}
By the uniqueness of distance $\bar x$, $\bar x$ is indeed the length-minimizing element in set $K$.

Further edit:
First, I shall translate my set $K$ and $x$ by $(-\bar x)$ so that we now have $(K - \bar x)$ and $x - \bar x$ instead of $K$ and $x$. Here, the $0$ will replace $\bar x$ in condition 2. For simplicity, let us call $K$ to denote our old $K-\bar x$ and $x$ to denote $x - \bar x$. Then, our condition 2. becomes:

> For this specific $x$, the following holds: for all $z \in K$, $\langle z, x \rangle \leq 0$.

Now, we need to tackle a question, "what would be $\tilde x \in K$ such that $d(\tilde x, x) = d(K, x)$? Assume by contradiction that distance minimizing $\tilde x$ is not $0$.

1. let us explore if $\tilde x$ would ever lie on the line segment between $0$ and $x$. This $\tilde x$ can be expressed as $\tilde x = \alpha x$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$. However, the problem with this $\tilde x$ is that this violates uniqueness of $\bar x$ in condition 2, i.e. for any $z \in K$, I also have $\langle x - \tilde x, z - \tilde x \rangle \leq 0$:

\begin{align*}
\langle x - \tilde x, z - \tilde x \rangle &= \langle x-\alpha x, z - \alpha x \rangle \\
&= \langle (1-\alpha)x, z - \alpha x \rangle \\
&= (1-\alpha)\langle x, z \rangle -\alpha(1-\alpha)\|x\|^2 \\
&< 0
\end{align*}

Hence, I can make a conclusion that a line segment from $0$ to $x$ cannot contain any point in $K$, i.e. $\{\alpha x \mid \alpha \in (0, 1)\} \cap K = \varnothing$.

2. From the previous case, we arrived to a conclusion that distance minimizing $\tilde x$ cannot lie on the line segment $\{\alpha x \mid \alpha \in (0, 1)\}$. So wherever $\tilde x$ is, we have $\langle x, \tilde x \rangle < 0$. Let $r = d(x, \tilde x)$ and we may assume $r \leq \|x\|$. Now, consider sphere $\partial B(x, r)$, and for any $y \in \partial B(x, r)$, we have $\langle x, y \rangle > 0$. (If $r = \|x\|$ and $y = \bar x$, then "$>$" is replaced by "$=$", but that is not what we want.) This implies that $\langle \tilde x, x \rangle > 0$ since $\tilde x \in \partial B(x,r)$. This contradicts our assumption that angle where $\langle x, \tilde x \rangle < 0$.

Thus, $0 \in K$ is unique distance-minimizing element from $x$. Going back to our original set $K$ before we translated everything by $\bar x$, note that choice of $x$ was arbitrary, so if we pick some other $x' \in \mathbb R^n$, we may repeat the same procedure to make the same conclusion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139122/discussion-on-question-by-james-c-closed-set-with-unique-distance-minimizing-ele).